# How to set the default web browser used to open URLs under i3?

Tags: i3, xdg-open

I have tried to set my default browser for opening URLs to Chromium using:

```
xdg-settings set default-web-browser chromium.desktop
```

(yes I checked out whether /usr/share/applications/chromium.desktop existed first before running this command and it does exist) and it returns:

```
xdg-settings: unknown desktop environment
```

i3 isn't a desktop environment so I can definitely understand this error, but is there a way around it? The reason I want xdg-open to open URLs using Chromium is that running `notebook()` from the SageMath command-line attempts to open the notebook in one's default web browser (using xdg-open). Presently this obviously fails (no browser, or application for that matter, is opened to the URL), so I'd like to get this to work which I believe will require me to get xdg-open to open URLs in Chromium.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install [perl-file-mimeinfo](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?name=perl-file-mimeinfo) and configure it that way. See the Arch Wiki article on [xdg-utils](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xdg-utils#xdg-open):

> If no desktop environment is detected, MIME type detection falls back
>   to using file which—ironically—does not implement the XDG standard. If
>   you want xdg-open to use XDG MIME Applications without a desktop
>   environment, *you will need to install perl-file-mimeinfo* or switch to
>   one of the resource openers that support XDG MIME Applications.

Answer (score 2):

I set it in */usr/share/applications/defaults.list* and it worked for me (opening links from the Slack app). Indeed, the list of available applications is */usr/share/applications/*.desktop*

These lines had to be edited in my case:

```
text/html=firefox.desktop;
text/xml=firefox.desktop;
application/xhtml_xml=firefox.desktop;
image/webp=firefox.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/http=firefox.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/https=firefox.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/ftp=firefox.desktop;
```

This can probably also be done per-user in *~/.config/mimeapps.list*